# Serverless: How to integrate gateway response using serverless library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

How to integrate gateway response using serverless framework?

I'm not able to find documentation in [serverless.com](https://serverless.com/) as well as in plugin [serverless-aws-documentation](https://github.com/9cookies/serverless-aws-documentation)

[image]

Comment: Gateway responses is a new feature and may not be supported yet. You may want to reach out on the GitHub project to request support: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added in resources section of `serverless.yml` as below

```
resources:
  Resources:
    Unauthorized:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseTemplates:
          "application/json": _${file(gateway-responses/responses.js):unauthorized}
        ResponseType: UNAUTHORIZED
        RestApiId: _${file(serverless.env.yml):_${self:provider.stage}.REST_API_ID}
        StatusCode: '401'
    Forbidden:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseTemplates:
          "application/json": _${file(gateway-responses/responses.js):forbidden}
        ResponseType: ACCESS_DENIED
        RestApiId: _${file(serverless.env.yml):_${self:provider.stage}.REST_API_ID}
        StatusCode: '403'
```

Answer (score -1):

Good question.  I believe you can do it in the `s-function.json` file like so:

```
"endpoints": [
{
  "path": "/test",
  "method": "GET",
  "authorizationType": "none",
  "apiKeyRequired": false,
  "requestParameters": {},
  "requestTemplates": {},
  "responses": {
    "400": {
      "statusCode": "400"
    },
    "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseParameters": {},
      "responseModels": {"text/html": "Empty"},
      "responseTemplates": {"text/html": "$input.json('$')"},
      "text/html": ""
    }
  }
}
]
```

Sources:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/587
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/463

Comment: This is related to `Gateway Response` not method response , so this answer will not work