# AWS API Gateway Responses via serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'd like to be able to configure API Gateway Responses via serverless framework...

[image: This is what I want to configure]

This is what my `serverless.yml` looks like:

```
#Deploy an api gateway with custom responses.
---
service: test-apigw
frameworkVersion: ">=3.20"

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  stackName: ${self:service}
  apiName: test-apigw
  endpointType: REGIONAL 

functions: 
  hello: 
    handler: handler.endpoint
    events: 
      - http:
          path: /hello-world
          method: ANY
          private: true

package:
  individually: true
  excludeDevDependencies: false
```

Now I read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493807/serverless-how-to-integrate-gateway-response-using-serverless-library) that one can configure `resources` in a serverless file, however by using CFN code I'd need the ARN or the Ref of an already deployed API Gateway or, declare the API Gateway with CFN code (which I want to avoid)...

Is there a way to configure these Gateway Responses (not integration responses!!) using the same api gateway that my `serverless.yml` is deploying? *i.e.* the one with name `test-apigw`?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the response I quoted actually works for me.
In the same `serverless.yml` file, put the GatewayResponses you want to configure.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    Unauthorized:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseTemplates:
          "application/json": ${file(gateway-responses/responses.js):unauthorized}
        ResponseType: UNAUTHORIZED
        RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
        StatusCode: '401'
```

At least for version 3.20 of serverless framework, the created API name is ApiGatewayRestApi, this will only work of course, if you're only creating one API Gw in that file and I believe, the API Gateway has to be already deployed.

The correct way to do this is, [as the official serverless documentation states](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#easiest-and-cicd-friendly-example-of-using-shared-api-gateway-and-api-resources), to create the API Gateway with Cloudformation code.

Comment: +1 Very valuable info. Exactly what I was looking for: allowing HTTP 401 responses from API Gateway to be caught sensibly in the browser without stumbling over nonsensical CORS errors -- and doing so via Serverless YAML. ...that said, it's stuff like this that makes me regret going the Serverless route. Very convenient at first, until you hit all these little hidden pitfalls that the Serverless creators seem to have never even thought of.